# Weblogic.socket.muxer warning in weblogic 9.2

Tags: weblogic

I got below warning in weblogic 9.2

```
Warning <Socket>  <managed2> <ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel

>> <> <> <> <BEA-000450> <Unable to find internal data record for the socket 7; event received
```

**Can it effect any performance in my application?**

If it effects, please provide a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ganesan Chandrasekaran.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a one-off or occurring frequently?

From the documentation

> BEA-000450
>
> Warning: Socket socket internal data record unavailable (probable
>   closure due idle timeout), event received event
>
> Description   Unable to find internal data record for the socket.
>
> **Cause   Server already closed the idle socket.**
>
> Action   If situation persists, contact Oracle Customer Support.

This is **mostly a harmless message** but you would need Oracle help if it is always appearing

This was also discussed on [the Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2183144)

> The root cause of this message is due to fixing the OutOfMemory
>   message being reported in an incident CR346335 for WebLogic 9.2 MP3.
>   Code changes  were made to explicitly remove the associated objects
>   from memory for a given socket after the timer thread closed the
>   socket as OS was not reporting  the error on the OS level. As a result
>   of the removal of the associated objects, the message starts appearing
>   in the log.